# If a data of the X-axis is empty, I don't want to display a data?

Tags: c#, .net, teechart

I'm using the Teechart version .Net and VS2005.

If a data of the X-axis is empty, I don't want to display a data.

I already have used the Axis break tool of Teechart function. but there are so many empty data in the chart. I need a other answer for that.

How can i do that?

Please help me!!!

[image]

my code :

```
datatable dt = new datatable();

Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Line line = new Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Line();
TChart1.Series.Add(line);

Steema.TeeChart.Axis axis = new Steema.TeeChart.Axis();
TChart1.Axes.Custom.Add(axis);

axis.StartPosition = 9;
axis.EndPosition = 11;
axis.Labels.Items.Add(0, " ");
axis.Labels.Items.Add(1, " ");
axis.Labels.Items[0].Visible = true;
axis.Labels.Items[1].Visible = true;
axis.Title.Caption = "A";
axis.Title.Font.Color = Color.Red;

DataRow row;
row = dt.NewRow();
row["X"] = "1";  //next input : 2, 3, 8, 9, 10 
row["Y"] = "1";  //next input : 1, 1, 0, 0,  0
dt.Rows.Add(row);

TChart1.Series[0].XValues.DataMember = "X";
TChart1.Series[0].YValues.DataMember = "Y";
TChart1.Series[0].DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: Remove the data you don't want. Show some code who you tried this.

Answer (score 0):

With AxisBreaks tool you can add a "*break*" for each gap in the data. You'll find an example at the *What's New?\Welcome !\New Chart Tools\Axis Break Tool* example in the features demo, available at TeeChart's program group.

An alternative is doing something similar to the example at *All Features\Welcome !\Chart styles\Financial\Candle (OHLC)\Axis Labels no Weekends* example in the demo.